# Jetpack Compose MutableTransitionState currentState holds wrong value

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-animation

I use `AnimatedVisibility` to animate deleting an item from a `LazyColumn` together with `MutableTransitionState` to catch the end of animation to delete this item from `LazyColumn`'s list.

I composed a handy extension function for this:

```
@ExperimentalTransitionApi
fun MutableTransitionState<Boolean>.transitionState(): TransitionState =
         if (this.isIdle && this.currentState)  TransitionState.Visible
    else if (this.isIdle && !this.currentState) TransitionState.Invisible
    else if (!this.isIdle && this.currentState) TransitionState.Disappearing
    else TransitionState.Appearing


enum class TransitionState(private val whatever: Int) {
    Visible(1),
    Appearing(2),
    Invisible(-1),
    Disappearing(-2)
}
```

It is correct in a sense that it returns correct values (tested), but `currentState` appears to be `false` only initially, so I can't catch the only event I'm interested in - `Invisible`.

Here is my `LazyColumn`:

```
val items by viewModel.itemsFlow.collectAsState()

LazyColumn(
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 15.dp, vertical = 15.dp)
) {
    items(items) { item ->
        val animationState = remember {
            MutableTransitionState(false) // The only time currentState is false!
        }.apply { targetState = true }
        AnimatedVisibility(
            visibleState = animationState,
            enter = slideInVertically() + fadeIn(),
            exit = slideOutHorizontally(
                targetOffsetX = { it*2 },
                animationSpec = tween(
                    durationMillis = 700
                )
            )
        ) {
            ItemCard(
                item = item,
                viewModel = viewModel,
                animationState = animationState
            )
        }
    }
}
```

My `ItemCard` has a `Button` that changes `animationState.tagetValue` to `false`, and the state is logged inside the card:

```
Card {
    Log.v("ANIMATION", "View ${item.name} is now ${animationState.transitionState().name}")
    Log.v("ANIMATION", "View ${item.name} has values: isIdle = ${animationState.isIdle}, currentState = ${animationState.currentState}")
        /*...*/
        Button(
            /*...*/
            onClick = {
                animationState.targetState = false
            }
        ) {/*...*/}
 }
```

My logs, quite unfortunately, are like this:

```
V/ANIMATION: View name is now Appearing
V/ANIMATION: View name has values: isIdle = false, currentState = false
V/ANIMATION: View name is now Appearing
V/ANIMATION: View name has values: isIdle = false, currentState = false
V/ANIMATION: View name is now Visible
V/ANIMATION: View name has values: isIdle = true, currentState = true
V/ANIMATION: View name is now Visible
V/ANIMATION: View name has values: isIdle = true, currentState = true
// After I click the button:
V/ANIMATION: View name is now Disappearing
V/ANIMATION: View name has values: isIdle = false, currentState = true
V/ANIMATION: View name is now Disappearing
V/ANIMATION: View name has values: isIdle = false, currentState = true
V/ANIMATION: View name is now Disappearing
V/ANIMATION: View name has values: isIdle = false, currentState = true
```

So where's the invisible state, i.e. `false` `currentState`? Have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### After some testing...

I tested this type of animation on a separate project and figured out that the `AnimatedVisibility` content gets disposed before the `animationState` emits its final value, so you can't possibly catch it from inside the view you are animating.

Following @Philip Dukhov advice, my `LazyColumn`s item is now like this:

```
            val animationState by remember {
                mutableStateOf(MutableTransitionState(false))
            }
            LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                animationState.targetState = true
            }
            when(animationState.transitionState()) {
                TransitionState.Invisible -> viewModel.deleteInvisibleItems()
                else -> {}
            }
            Log.v("ANIMATION", "View ${item.name} is now ${animationState.transitionState().name}")
```

This catches emitted values perfectly.

However, it has significant performance issues, which logcat shows:

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=992ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=189347804710717, Vsync=189348454710691, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=189348467819123, AnimationStart=189348467823342, PerformTraversalsStart=189348779946237, DrawStart=189348780275977, SyncQueued=189348792306499, SyncStart=189348792749051, IssueDrawCommandsStart=189348793026916, SwapBuffers=189348794352801, FrameCompleted=189348797854572, DequeueBufferDuration=181354, QueueBufferDuration=287916, GpuCompleted=188965731175579,
```

And I can't really figure out how to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you change state, it triggers related views recomposition. And you set `animationState` to `true` on each recomposition with `.apply { targetState = true }`.

Most likely you want to show it animated at the beginning, then you need to use [`LaunchedEffect`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#LaunchedEffect(kotlin.Any,kotlin.coroutines.SuspendFunction1)): it will be called only once when the view appears.

```
val animationState = remember {
    MutableTransitionState(false)
}
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    animationState.targetState = true
}
```

Read more about recompositions in [Thinking in Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model) and about state in Compose in [state documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state).

Comment: I believe this is not the problem. The state emits correct values on `enter` animation either way, and does not emit `Invisible` state on `exit` finished.